# ReactJS setState with multiple nested arrays- how add new object into sub-array

Tags: react-native

How do I add new item into sub-array by `setState`

```
getInitialState : function(){
            return { 
               Todo:[
             {
               name:"parimary",
               items:[
                {item:'Todo itmd #1',isDone:false},
                {item:'Todo itmd #2',isDone:true}
               ]
             },{
               name:"Secondary",
               items:[
                {item:'Todo itmd #1',isDone:false},
                {item:'Todo itmd #2',isDone:true},
                {item:'Todo itmd #3',isDone:true}
             ]}],selectedItem:"0"};

        },


InsertItems : function(newItem){
            var item = {item:newItem,isDone:false};
            var allItems = this.state.Todo[this.state.selectedItem].items.concat([item]);
            this.setState({
                Todo: {[this.state.selectedItem]:{items:{
            $set: allItems
          }}}
            });

        },
```

after I run, I just get a error

> Uncaught TypeError: allitems.map is not a function.

How do I can add a new object into sub-array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need to install the react native addons update:

```
$ npm i --save react-addons-update
```

Than import it inside you component:

```
import update from 'react-addons-update';
```

and than use the code below inside your ***InsertItems*** function for updated your nested array:

```
InsertItems : function(newItem){
     const item = {item: newItem, isDone: false};

     const index = this.state.selectedItem;

     const allItems = this.state.Todo[index].items.concat([item]);

     let newTodo = update(this.state.Todo, {
         [index]: {
             $set: {
                 ...this.state.Todo[index],
                 items: allItems
             }
         }
     });

     this.setState({Todo: newTodo});
 }
```